# MongoDB Split document field into two fields

Tags: json, mongodb, split

I have a MongoDB document with over 2.8m documents of common passwords (hashed in SHA1) and their popularity.

Currently I've imported the documents with the following schema

```
{"_id":"5ded1a559015155eb8295f48","password":"20EABE5D64B0E216796E834F52D61FD0B70332FC:2512537"}
```

Although I'd like to split this so I can have the popularity value and it would look something like this

```
{"_id":"5ded1a559015155eb8295f48","password":"20EABE5D64B0E216796E834F52D61FD0B70332FC","popularity":2512537}
```

Question is im unsure how I can split the `password` into two `password`, `popularity` using `:` to split the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework to split current `password` into two fields. You need to start with [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) to get the position of `:` and then you need [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/index.html#exp._S_substr) to create new fields based on evaluated position.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            colonPos: { $indexOfBytes: ["$password",":"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            password: { $substr: [ "$password", 0, "$colonPos" ] },
            popularity: { $substr: [ "$password", "$colonPos", { $strLenBytes: "$password" } ]  }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            colonPos: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nFgsTeZR27X)

As a last step you can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) which takes all your aggregation results and writes them into new or existing collection.

EDIT: Alternative approach using [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/index.html) (thank to @matthPen):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { 
            password: { $arrayElemAt: [ { "$split": [ "$password", ":"] }, 0 ] },
            popularity: { $arrayElemAt: [ { "$split": [ "$password", ":"] }, 1 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9rjOCnZ5Mz6)

Comment: Just to know : why not simply use $split here?

Comment: @matthPen $split makes sense here, modified my answer, thank you !